# Terraform: How to read the volume ID of one instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I create instances with a default CentOS 7 AMI. This AMI creates automatically a volume and attached to the instance. Is it possible to read thats volume ID using terraform? I create the instance using the next code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "DCOS-master3" {
    ami = "${var.aws_centos_ami}"
    availability_zone = "eu-west-1b"
    instance_type = "t2.medium"
    key_name = "${var.aws_key_name}"
    security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.bastion.id}"]
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    private_ip = "10.0.0.13"
    source_dest_check = false
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.eu-west-1b-public.id}"

    tags {
            Name = "master3"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't be able to extract EBS details from `aws_instance` since it's AWS side that provides an EBS volume to the resource.

But you can define a EBS `data source` with some filter.

```
data "aws_ebs_volume" "ebs_volume" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "attachment.instance-id"
    values = ["${aws_instance.DCOS-master3.id}"]
  }
}

output "ebs_volume_id" {
  value = "${data.aws_ebs_volume.ebs_volume.id}"
}
```

You can refer EBS filters here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-volumes.html

Answer (score 1):

You can: `aws_instance.DCOS-master3.root_block_device.0.volume_id`

As described in [Terraform docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#attributes-reference):

> For any `root_block_device` and `ebs_block_device` the `volume_id` is exported. e.g. `aws_instance.web.root_block_device.0.volume_id`

Answer (score 1):

```
output "volume-id-C" {
  description = "root volume-id"
  #get the root volume id form the instance
     value       =  element(tolist(data.aws_instance.DCOS-master3.root_block_device.*.volume_id),0)
}

output "volume-id-D" {
   description = "ebs-volume-id"
    #get the 1st esb volume id form the instance
        value       =  element(tolist(data.aws_instance.DCOS-master3.ebs_block_device.*.volume_id),0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **get** the volume name of an `aws_instance` like this:

```
output "instance" {
    value = aws_instance.ec2_instance.volume_tags["Name"]
}
```

And you can **set** it as follows:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instance" {
  ami                   = var.instance_ami
  instance_type         = var.instance_type
  key_name              = var.instance_key
  ...
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.server_name}_${var.instance_name[count.index]}"
  }
  volume_tags = {
    Name = "local_${var.instance_name[count.index]}"
  } 
}
```